File attachement problems with thunderbird 128esr
Since Thunderbird 128esr (115esr is ok, and after, I jumped to 128esr in september), attaching a file to an email is not working properly : the drag and drop function doesn't work any more.
I tried to reinstall TB, but it does exactly the same with this version.
system : Lubuntu 22.04, up to date
Thunderbird 128.4 (up to date).
If somebody have the same and have a hint, that would be great to share.

Is Thunderbird installed as a snap package? Append to your question the result of 'sudo snap list' Also, do you know if the 115esr was a snap rather than an apt?

Might try a different file manager.  I found pcmanfm-qt doesn't work, but pcmanfm and thunar do.
